# Red lines in storyboard right from the start and with all controls added -- Xcode 6.3

Tags: ios, autolayout, interface-builder

I'm stumped.  In Xcode 6.3 I get red lines as if I have constraint problems as soon as I create a new project.  There are 2 red lines - one outlining the view and the other for the margin.   This is how it starts.  It shows more red lines for every control I add.  Each control has a red outline and a second line directly under the text (w/ no margin).  I would post pictures, but I need to earn some reputation points here.

I don't see any settings that would make this happen in Xcode.  I even completely deleted Xcode and re-downloaded & installed from the app store.  Does anyone know how to get rid of these?

Comment: Did you perhaps do Editor > Canvas > Show Layout Rectangles or Show Bounds Rectangles?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to your question?

Comment: This question is absolutely useless without pictures and absolutely clear steps for reproducing the problem.

Comment: You got it!  Thanks so much.  This has been driving me crazy as I'm trying to learn Xcode better.  it was the Layout Rectangles.

Comment: A little rough there nhgrif -- Ken Thomases solved it no problem.

Answer (score 0):

It was resolved by deselecting Editor>Canvas>Show Layout Rectangles.  Thanks Ken Thomases.

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to click on the view that has the problem and then use
Editor -> Resolve Auto Layout Issues -> Update Frames.

Comment: There is no problem to resolve.  It's just the generic single view application template.